# Check if a string is a shuffle of two other given strings

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a question from *The Algorithm Design Manual*:

> Suppose you are given three strings of characters: `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, where `|X| = n`,
>   `|Y| = m`, and `|Z| = n+m.` `Z` is said to be a shuffle of `X` and `Y` if and only if `Z` can be formed by interleaving the characters from `X` and `Y` in a way that maintains the left-to ­right ordering of the characters from each string.
>
> Give an efficient dynamic ­programming algorithm that determines whether `Z` is a shuffle of `X` and `Y`.
>
> Hint: the values of the dynamic programming matrix you construct should be Boolean, not numeric

This is what I tried:

Initially, I made a 1-D char array and pointers to the starting characters of X,Y,Z respectively. If Z-pointer with matches X-pointer store X in the char array else check the same with Y-pointer.If each entry in the char array is not different from its last entry, Z is not interleaved.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @Mörre No this is not my homework. I have only quoted *The Algorithm Design Manual*

Comment: You will have to show some effort yourself if you want a good response from SO.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal.This is what I tried: Initially,I made a 1-D char array and pointers to the starting characters of X,Y,Z respectively. If Z-pointer with matches X-pointer store X in the char array else check the same with Y-pointer.If each entry in the char array is not different from its last entry, Z is not interleaved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following approach should give you an idea.

Define the condition `d(s1,s2,s3) = (s1 + s2 == s3) { s3 is a shuffle of s1 and s2 }`

We have to find `d( X, Y, Z )`.

if lengths of s1 and s2 are 1 each and length of s3 = 2,

```
d( s1,s2,s3 ) = { (s1[0] == s3[0] && s2[0] == s3[1]) || (s1[0] == s3[1] && s2[0] == s3[0])
```

Similarly d can be obtained for empty strings.

For strings of arbitrary length, following relation holds.

```
d( s1,s2,s3 ) = { ( d( s1-s1[last],s2,s3 - s3[last]) && s1[last] == s3[last] )
                  || ( d( s1,s2 - s2[last],s3 - s3[last]) && s2[last] == s3[last] )
                }
```

You can compute the `d()` entries starting from zero length strings and keep checking.

Comment: doesn't interleaving imply that successive characters in Z need to be from X and Y alternatively ?

Comment: No. Interleaving only implies that Z should contain all the characters in X and Y and in the same order as they were in the respective strings. For example, abc and def and be interleaved to form abcdef.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's start with some definitions. I write `X[i]` for the `i`th element of `X` and `X[i)` for the substring of `X` starting at index `i`.

For example, if `X = abcde`, then `X[2] = c` and `X[2) = cde`.

Similar definitions hold for `Y` and `Z`.

---

To solve the problem by dynamic programming, you should keep a 2D boolean array `A` of size `(n+1) x (m+1)`. In this array, `A[i, j] = true` if and only if `X[i)` and `Y[j)` can be interleaved to form `Z[i+j)`.

For an arbitrary `(i, j)`, somewhere in the middle of the 2D array, the recurrence relation is very simple:

```
A[i, j] := X[i] = Z[i+j] and A[i+1, j]
        or Y[j] = Z[i+j] and A[i, j+1]
```

On the edges of the 2D array you have the case that either `X` or `Y` is already at its end, which means the suffix of the other should be equal to the suffix of `Z`:

```
A[m, j] := Y[j) = Z[m+j)
A[i, n] := X[i) = Z[i+n)
A[m, n] := true
```

---

If you first fill the border of the array (`A[m, j]` and `A[i, n]`, for all `i, j`), you can then simply loop back towards `A[0, 0]` and set the entries appropriately. In the end `A[0, 0]` is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined by following recurrence relation:-

```
S(i,j,k) = false

if(Z(i)==Y(k))
  S(i,j,k) = S(i,j,k)||S(i+1,j,k+1)

if(Z(i)==X(j))
  S(i,j,k) = S(i,j,k)||S(i+1,j+1,k)

Where S(i,j,k) corresponds to Z[i to end] formed by shuffle of X[j to end] and Y[K to end]
```

You should try to code this into DP on your own.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is quite easy if you are solving this problem by using this approach with java**

**Java Based Solution**

```
public class ValidShuffle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
        String s1 = "XY";
        String s2 = "12";

        String results = "Y21XX";
    
        validShuffle(s1, s2, results);

    }

    private static void validShuffle(String s1, String s2, String result) {
        
        String s3 = s1 + s2;
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(s3);

        boolean flag = false;

        char[] ch = result.toCharArray();

        if (s.length() != result.length()) {
            flag = false;
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                
                String temp = Character.toString(ch[i]);

                if (s3.contains(temp)) {

                    s = s.deleteCharAt(s.indexOf(temp));
                    s3 = new String(s);
                    flag = true;
                    
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        if (flag) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }

    }

}
```

If any problem in my code then comment me please. ***thank you***

Answer (score 0):

```
    function checkShuffle(str1, str2, str3) {
      var merge=str1+str2;
      var charArr1= merge.split("").sort();
      var charArr2= str3.split("").sort();
      for(i=0;i<str3.length;i++){
         if(charArr1[i] == charArr2[i]){
            return true; 
         }
      }    
     return false;
   }
checkShuffle("abc", "def", "dfabce"); //output is true
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT BASED SOLUTION

```
 const first = "bac";
 const second = "def"
 const third = "dabecf";

function createDict(seq,str){
   let strObj = {};
   str = str.split("");
   str.forEach((letter,index)=>{
   strObj[letter] = {
       wordSeq: seq,
       index : index

   } ;
   })
   return strObj;
 }

function checkShuffleValidity(thirdWord,firstWord,secondWord){
    let firstWordDict = createDict('first',firstWord);
    let secondWordDict = createDict('second',secondWord);
    let wordDict = {...firstWordDict,...secondWordDict};
    let firstCount=0,secondCount = 0;
    thirdWord = thirdWord.split("");
    for(let i=0; i<thirdWord.length; i++){
        let letter = thirdWord[i];
         if(wordDict[letter].wordSeq == "first"){
      if(wordDict[letter].index === firstCount){
         firstCount++;
      }else{
        return false
      }        
    }else{
    if(wordDict[letter].index === secondCount){
      secondCount++;
    }else{
      return false;
    }

    }
}  
return true;
}

 console.log(checkShuffleValidity(third,first,second));
```

Answer (score -1):

Key points:

1. All strings shouldn't be null or empty.
2. The sum of the 2 strings length should be equal to the third string.
3. The third string should not contain the substrings of the 2 strings.
4. Else create arrays of characters , sort and compare.

Code:

```
public static boolean validShuffle(String first, String second, String third){
  boolean status=false;
  if((first==null || second==null || third==null) || (first.isEmpty()|| second.isEmpty() || third.isEmpty())){
    status = false;
  } else if((first.length()+second.length()) !=third.length()){
    //check if the sum of 2 lengths equals to the third string length
    status = false;
  } else if(third.indexOf(first,0)!=-1 || third.indexOf(second,0)!=-1){
    //check if the third string contains substrings
    status = false;
  } else {
    char [] c1_2=(first+second).toCharArray();
    char [] c3 =third.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c1_2);
    Arrays.sort(c3);
    status=Arrays.equals(c1_2, c3);
  }
  return status;
}
```